# Any tool or online platform which when provided with a deployed contract address and it's abi, shows the methods of that contract?

Tags: abi

I have an unverified deployed smart contract and I have the ABI of that contract, now how can I get the list of methods inside that contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etherscan has an option to add custom ABIs.

Top right hand corner.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]